# Make a rectangle follow a trajectory

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to make the center of a rectangle follow a trajectory and rotate it according to the trajectory, like the ones shown in this video (the video doesn't have a trajectory but shows a simple rotating rectangle)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT45HE7L7yk.

So far this is my code

```
figure; 
subplot(2,1,1)
%visualize trajectory
ax = gca;
h = hgtransform('Parent',ax);
hold on
plot(x(1),y(1),'o','Parent',h);
for k = 2:length(x)
    m = makehgtform('translate',x(k)-x(1),y(k)-y(1),0);
    h.Matrix = m;
    axis([2 10 2 10]);
    drawnow
end
subplot(2,1,2)
ax = gca;
polyin = polyshape([0.1 0.1 -0.1 -0.1], [0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2]); % %w/2,h/2
% polyin = rectangle('Position',[-0.1 -0.1 0.2, 0.4]);
polyout = rotate(polyin, -atand(Y(1)/X(1)));
polyout = translate(polyout,[X(1) Y(1)]);
plot(polyout);
axis([2 10 2 10]);
for k=2:length(x)
    hold on;
    t = atan((y(k-1)-y(k))/(x(k)-x(k-1)))
%     t = acos((y(k-1)*x(k-1)+y(k)*x(k))/(norm([x(k-1) y(k-1)])*norm([x(k) y(k)])));
%     t = atand(y(k))/(x(k));
    if (x(k)* y(k-1)- y(k)*x(k-1) )< 0
        t = -1*t;
    end
    polyout=translate(polyout,x(k)-x(k-1),y(k)-y(k-1));
    polyout=rotate(polyout, t);
    plot(polyout);
    axis([2 10 2 10]);
    drawnow;
end
```

I want the rectangle to rotate towards the next point in trajectory, and the center to follow the trajectory however my code is not working right. 
Any help is very much appreciated thank you for your time.

x and y data for reference

```
x=[2    2.20138766511364    2.40315325924044    2.60463533746946    2.80522353545458    3.00435711210347    3.20152349226664    3.39625680942646    3.58813644838617    3.77678558795894    3.96186974365685    4.14309531037993    4.32020810510520    4.49299190957566    4.66126701298937    4.82488875468838    4.98374606684784    5.13776001716501    5.28688235154823    5.43109403680600    5.57040380333597    5.70484668781400    5.83448257588312    5.95939474484264    6.07968840633708    6.19548924904527    6.30694198136934    6.41420887412373    6.51746830322425    6.61691329237706    6.71275005576773    6.80519654075027    6.89448097053608    6.98084038688309    7.06451919278466    7.14576769515872    7.22484064753668    7.30199579275257    7.37749240563194    7.45158983568100    7.52454604977557    7.59661617485011    7.66805104058679    7.73909572210444    7.80998808264764    7.88095731627572    7.95222249055176    8.02399108923166    8.09645755495312    8.16980183192468    8.24418790861475    8.31976236044063    8.39665289245752    8.47496688204757    8.55478992160887    8.63618436124451    8.71918785145157    8.80381188581016    8.89004034367245    8.97782803285167    9.06709923231116    9.15774623485338    9.24962788980894    9.34256814572560    9.43635459305732    9.53073700685329    9.62542588944692    9.72009101314488    9.81435996291615    9.90781667908099    10]

y=[2    2.02032989606539    2.04061708413251    2.06134914940940    2.08296946958339    2.10587858004199    2.13043553909377    2.15695929318928    2.18573004214188    2.21699060434868    2.25094778201139    2.28777372635721    2.32760730285977    2.37055545645991    2.41669457678668    2.46607186337814    2.51870669090231    2.57459197437800    2.63369553439574    2.69596146233865    2.76131148560331    2.82964633282069    2.90084709907698    2.97477661113452    3.05128079265267    3.13019002940870    3.21132053451867    3.29447571365832    3.37944753028395    3.46601787085333    3.55395991004655    3.64303947598694    3.73301641546193    3.82364595914396    3.91468008681135    4.00586889256917    4.09696195007019    4.18770967773568    4.27786470397637    4.36718323241328    4.45542640709865    4.54236167773681    4.62776416490505    4.71141802527453    4.79311781683116    4.87266986409647    4.94989362334853    5.02462304784280    5.09670795303304    5.16601538179218    5.23243096963322    5.29586030993012    5.35623031913866    5.41349060201735    5.46761481684833    5.51860204065821    5.56647813443899    5.61129710836894    5.65314248703349    5.69212867464610    5.72840232026917    5.76214368303492    5.79356799736624    5.82292683819765    5.85050948619610    5.87664429298192    5.90170004634970    5.92608733548913    5.95025991620594    5.97471607614275    6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the rectangle to rotate around its center you should specify the reference point of rotation to be the center of the rectangle. Secondly, when rotating you have to keep in mind that in the previous step you already did a rotation and therefore need to substract the previous angle from the new one.

```
polyin = polyshape([0.1 0.1 -0.1 -0.1], [0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2]); % %w/2,h/2
% polyin = rectangle('Position',[-0.1 -0.1 0.2, 0.4]);
polyout = translate(polyout,[x(1) y(1)]); 
plot(polyout);
axis([2 10 2 10]);
prev_t = 0;
for k=2:length(x)
    hold on;
    t = atan((y(k)-y(k-1))/(x(k)-x(k-1)))  % corrected formula

%    if (x(k)* y(k-1)- y(k)*x(k-1) )< 0    % commented because I don't see why this should be here
%        t = -1*t;
%    end

    polyout=translate(polyout,x(k)-x(k-1),y(k)-y(k-1));
    polyout=rotate(polyout, t - prev_t, [x(k) y(k)]);
    plot(polyout);
    axis([2 10 2 10]);
    drawnow;
    prev_t = t;
end
```

Comment: wow thanks! i was completely oblivious to this part `polyout=rotate(polyout, t - prev_t, [x(k) y(k)]);`  this does work, however it doesn't seem to rotate enough to put the rectangles heading on the curve, it does translate very well.

Comment: edit: I fixed this, thank you so much for your help, i spent nearly 2 days trying to figure this part out!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Comment: Hi ViG! sorry to bother you again, i thought i solved the heading problem that day, looks like i couldn't do it entirely, i have used your code with little modification, can you please see the question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54606363/961682 and answer if possible. thank you.