# Simple rotation of a rectangle along a curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, robotics

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle(polyshape) in matlab to orient itself along the curve(a set of points). So far this is my code.

```
l=2;w=1;xc=-1;yc=2;
xvs= [xc+w/2 xc+w/2 xc-w/2 xc-w/2];
yvs= [yc-l/2 yc+l/2 yc+l/2 yc-l/2];
ax = gca;
polyin = polyshape(xvs,yvs); % %w/2,h/2% polyin = rectangle('Position',[-0.1 -0.1 0.2, 0.4]);
k=2;
% t = acos((y(k-1)*x(k-1)+y(k)*x(k))/(norm([x(k-1) y(k-1)])*norm([x(k) y(k)])));
t = atan(y(k)/x(k));
polyout = translate(polyin,[-xc -yc]);
polyout = translate(polyout,[x(1) y(1)]);
polyout = rotate(polyout, t, [x(2) y(2)]);
plot(polyout);
axis([-4 4 0 50]);
prev_t = atan(y(2)/x(2));
for k=2:length(x)
    cla();
    t = atan((y(k)-y(k-1))/(x(k)-x(k-1)));
%     t = acos((y(k-1)*x(k-1)+y(k)*x(k))/(norm([x(k-1) y(k-1)])*norm([x(k) y(k)])));
%     t = atan((y(k-1))/(x(k-1)));
    polyout=translate(polyout,x(k)-x(k-1),y(k)-y(k-1));
    [t3,t4]=centroid(polyout);
    t-prev_t
    polyout=rotate(polyout,rad2deg(t-prev_t) ,[t3, t4] );%, );
    prev_t = t;
    plot(polyout);
    hold on;
    plot(x(1:k),y(1:k));
    hold on; 
    quiver(x(k), y(k), 1, 1);
    axis([-4 4 0 50]);
    drawnow;
end
```

x,y is listed below

```
x = [-1 -1.00972272933410   -1.01870478051530   -1.02695805761983   -1.03449438259277   -1.04132549543428   -1.04746305438566   -1.05291863611549   -1.05770373590578   -1.06182976783809   -1.06530806497965   -1.06814987956949   -1.07036638320459   -1.07196866702597   -1.07296774190485   -1.07337453862878   -1.07319990808774   -1.07245462146029   -1.07114937039970   -1.06929476722009   -1.06690134508251   -1.06397955818112   -1.06053978192930   -1.05659231314578   -1.05214737024076   -1.04721509340205   -1.04180554478121   -1.03592870867963   -1.02959449173473   -1.02281272310602   -1.01559315466128   -1.00794546116266   -0.999879240452816  -0.991404013641053  -0.982529225289427  -0.973264243598892  -0.963618360595424  -0.953600792316151  -0.943220678995479  -0.932487085251223  -0.921409000270737  -0.909995337997038  -0.898254937314939  -0.886196562237176  -0.873828902090537  -0.861160571701991  -0.848200111584816  -0.834955988124727  -0.821436593766009  -0.807650247197639  -0.793605193539421  -0.779309604528111  -0.764771578703544  -0.749999141594771  -0.735000245906179  -0.719782771703621  -0.704354526600550  -0.688723245944142  -0.672896593001429  -0.656882159145424  -0.640687464041251  -0.624319955832276  -0.607787011326233  -0.591095936181355  -0.574253965092497  -0.557268261977274  -0.540145920162182  -0.522893962568731  -0.505519341899570  -0.488028940824620  -0.470429572167200  -0.452727979090155  -0.434930835281988  -0.417044745142986  -0.399076243971348  -0.381031798149319  -0.362917805329311  -0.344740594620036  -0.326506426772637  -0.308221494366812  -0.289891921996946  -0.271523766458236  -0.253123016932825  -0.234695595175927  -0.216247355701956  -0.197784085970655  -0.179311506573228  -0.160835271418462  -0.142360967918861  -0.123894117176775  -0.105440174170524  -0.0870045279405308 -0.0685925017754495 -0.0502093533982922 -0.0318602751525592 -0.0135503941883670 0.00471522735142232 0.0229315921450729  0.0410937675058457  0.0591968851958715  0.0772361412400196  0.0952067957397721  0.113104172687091   0.130923659778296   0.148660708227926   0.166310832582623   0.183869610534992   0.201332682737479   0.218695752616237   0.235954586185006   0.253105011858973   0.270142920268653   0.287064264073754   0.303865057777052   0.320541377538260   0.337089360987901   0.353505207041178   0.369785175711844   0.385925587926079   0.401922825336353   0.417773330135305   0.433473604869608   0.449020212253846   0.464409774984379   0.479638975553221   0.494704556061906   0.509603318035363   0.524332122235782   0.538887888476493   0.553267595435832   0.567468280471012   0.581487039431996   0.595321026475369   0.608967453878208   0.622423591851952   0.635686768356277   0.648754368912964   0.661623836419772   0.674292670964308   0.686758429637899   0.699018726349463   0.711071231639382   0.722913672493370   0.734543832156346   0.745959549946308   0.757158721068200   0.768139296427783   0.778899282445511   0.789436740870399   0.799749788593894   0.809836597463747   0.819695394097884   0.829324459698281   0.838722129864827   0.847886794409204   0.856816897168752   0.865510935820345   0.873967461694257   0.882185079588040   0.890162447580389   0.897898276845016   0.905391331464524   0.912640428244272   0.919644436526252   0.926402278002956   0.932912926531251   0.939175407946249   0.945188799875176   0.950952231551246   0.956464883627534   0.961725987990839   0.966734827575568   0.971490736177594   0.975993098268136   0.980241348807631   0.984234973059598   0.987973506404514   0.991456534153687   0.994683691363123   0.997654662647400   1.00036918199354    1.00282703257487    1.00502804656492    1.00697210495126    1.00865913734939    1.01008912181662    1.01126208466593    1.01217810027981    1.01283729092421    1.01323982656233    1.01338592466854    1.01327585004223    1.01290991462170    1.01228847729801    1.01141194372885    1.01028076615244    1.00889544320138    1.00725651971651    1.00536458656082    1.00322028043328    1.00082428368272    0.998177324121733   0.995280174840507   0.992133654020716   0.988738624749389   0.985095994832775   0.981206716610224   0.977071786768050   0.972692246153409   0.968069179588162   0.963203715682755   0.958097026650084   0.952750328119371   0.947164878950031   0.941341981045545   0.935282979167332   0.928989260748622   0.922462255708321   0.915703436264890   0.908714316750211   0.901496453423459   0.894051444284976   0.886380928890139   0.878486588163234   0.870370144211326   0.862033360138129   0.853478039857879   0.844706027909207   0.835719209269005   0.826519509166304   0.817108892896138   0.807489365633420   0.797662972246815   0.787631797112606   0.777397963928569   0.766963635527843   0.756331013692799   0.745502338968920   0.734479890478659   0.723265985735320   0.711862980456928   0.700273268380098   0.688499281073906   0.676543487753763   0.664408395095284   0.652096547048159   0.639610524650029   0.626952945840348   0.614126465274265   0.601133774136485   0.587977599955151   0.574660706415706   0.561185893174769   0.547555995674006   0.533773884953999   0.519842467468121   0.505764684896401   0.491543513959404   0.477181966232097   0.462683087957718   0.448049959861653   0.433285696965303   0.418393448399959   0.403376397220668   0.388237760220109   0.372980787742464   0.357608763497285   0.342125004373370   0.326532860252634   0.310835713823975   0.295036980397154   0.279140107716656   0.263148575775570   0.247065896629457   0.230895614210219   0.214641304139976   0.198306573544930   0.181895060869242   0.165410435688903   0.148856398525599   0.132236680660593   0.115555043948583   0.0988152806315876  0.0820212131528061  0.0651766939704940  0.0482856053718364  0.0313518592868137  0.0143793971020798  -0.00262781052517255    -0.0196657638533383 -0.0367304342425269 -0.0538177643406945 -0.0709236682697698 -0.0880440318117838 -0.105174712595000  -0.122311540280039  -0.139450316746014  -0.156586816276652  -0.173716785746427  -0.190835944806689  -0.207939986071788  -0.225024575305211  -0.242085351605702  -0.259117927593395  -0.276117889595944  -0.293080797834649  -0.310002186610585  -0.326877564490733  -0.343702414494106  -0.360472194277880  -0.377182336323518  -0.393828248122908  -0.410405312364482  -0.426908887119349  -0.443334306027426  -0.459676878483560  -0.475931889823665  -0.492094601510844  -0.508160251321521  -0.524124053531569  -0.539981199102440  -0.555726855867290  -0.571356168717112  -0.586864259786862  -0.602246228641589  -0.617497152462564  -0.632612086233408  -0.647586062926218  -0.662414093687702  -0.677091168025301  -0.691612253993325  -0.705972298379074  -0.720166226888972  -0.734188944334692  -0.748035334819290  -0.761700261923330  -0.775178568891010  -0.788465078816297  -0.801554594829052  -0.814441900281157  -0.827121758932650  -0.839588915137848  -0.851838094031477  -0.863864001714800  -0.875661325441750  -0.887224733805055  -0.898548876922365  -0.909628386622385  -0.920457876631001  -0.931031942757411  -0.941345163080250  -0.951392098133724  -0.961167291093732  -0.970665267964000  -0.979880537762209  -0.988807592706122  -0.997440908399714  -1.00577494401930   -1.01380414249966   -1.02152293072018   -1.02892571969097   -1.03600690473899   -1.04276086569418   -1.04918196707561   -1.05526455827758   -1.06100297375575   -1.06639153321331   -1.07142454178703   -1.07609629023348   -1.08040105511509   -1.08433309898632   -1.08788667057976   -1.09105600499228   -1.09383532387113   -1.09621883560011   -1.09820073548567   -1.09977520594304   -1.10093641668239   -1.10167852489489   -1.10199567543892   -1.10188200102614   -1.10133162240765   -1.10033864856010   -1.09889717687183   -1.09700129332900   -1.09464507270172   -1.09182257873014   -1.08852786431066   -1.08475497168197   -1.08049793261124   -1.07575076858022   -1.07050749097139   -1.06476210125405   -1.05850859117050   -1.05174094292213   -1.04445312935557   -1.03663911414879   -1.02829285199726   -1.01940828880009   -1.00997936184609   -1]    

y = [2  2.26499544506307    2.52345285165919    2.77551012741366    3.02130356526704    3.26096785177083    3.49463607538307    3.72243973476395    3.94450874707147    4.16097145625704    4.37195464136115    4.57758352480892    4.77798178070582    4.97327154313322    5.16357341444407    5.34900647355850    5.52968828425946    5.70573490348834    5.87726088964058    6.04437931086135    6.20720175334112    6.36583832961133    6.52039768683998    6.67098701512728    6.81771205580129    6.96067710971352    7.09998504553457    7.23573730804975    7.36803392645471    7.49697352265110    7.62265331954214    7.74516914932828    7.86461546180284    7.98108533264758    8.09467047172843    8.20546123139099    8.31354661475628    8.41901428401626    8.52195056872954    8.62244047411698    8.72056768935728    8.81641459588266    8.91006227567448    9.00159051955883    9.09107783550219    9.17860145690705    9.26423735090754    9.34806022666506    9.43014354366389    9.51055952000682    9.58937914071082    9.66667216600261    9.74250713961429    9.81695139707904    9.89007107402665    9.96193111447923    10.0325952791468    10.1021261537228    10.1705851571801    10.2380325500660    10.3045274427986    10.3701278039618    10.4348904686013    10.4988711465199    10.5621244305736    10.6247038049668    10.6866616535481    10.7480492681059    10.8089168566642    10.8693135517778    10.9292874188284    10.9888854643200    11.0481536441744    11.1071368720271    11.1658790275228    11.2244229646110    11.2828105198417    11.3410825206610    11.3992787937066    11.4574381731036    11.5155985087602    11.5737966746629    11.6320685771728    11.6904491633205    11.7489724291023    11.8076714277756    11.8665782781543    11.9257241729050    11.9851393868420    12.0448532852234    12.1048943320464    12.1652900983432    12.2260672704765    12.2872516584350    12.3488682041292    12.4109409896870    12.4734932457494    12.5365473597658    12.6001248842901    12.6642465452759    12.7289322503726    12.7942010972203    12.8600713817463    12.9265606064601    12.9936854887492    13.0614619691748    13.1299052197674    13.1990296523224    13.2688489266957    13.3393759590994    13.4106229303974    13.4826012944010    13.5553217861645    13.6287944302809    13.7030285491776    13.7780327714119    13.8538150399664    13.9303826205452    14.0077421098691    14.0858994439713    14.1648599064931    14.2446281369795    14.3252081391748    14.4066032893182    14.4888163444396    14.5718494506550    14.6557041514622    14.7403813960366    14.8258815475266    14.9122043913492    14.9993491434859    15.0873144587782    15.1760984392230    15.2656986422686    15.3561120891100    15.4473352729848    15.5393641674687    15.6321942347710    15.7258204340304    15.8202372296108    15.9154385993964    16.0114180430878    16.1081685904975    16.2056828098453    16.3039528160545    16.4029702790468    16.5027264320383    16.6032120798353    16.7044176071297    16.8063329867944    16.9089477881795    17.0122511854074    17.1162319656689    17.2208785375182    17.3261789391692    17.4321208467907    17.5386915828022    17.6458781241694    17.7536671107000    17.8620448533392    17.9709973424653    18.0805102561854    18.1905689686311    18.3011585582540    18.4122638161214    18.5238692542118    18.6359591137108    18.7485173733063    18.8615277574846    18.9749737448257    19.0888385762990    19.2031052635592    19.3177565972414    19.4327751552571    19.5481433110899    19.6638432420907    19.7798569377739    19.8961662081124    20.0127526918339    20.1295978647159    20.2466830478817    20.3639894160961    20.4814980060606    20.5991897247094    20.7170453575050    20.8350455767337    20.9531709498011    21.0714019475281    21.1897189524464    21.3081022670938    21.4265321223103    21.5449886855333    21.6634520690937    21.7819023385110    21.9003195207895    22.0186836127132    22.1369745891423    22.2551724113081    22.3732570351088    22.4912084194057    22.6090065343178    22.7266313695183    22.8440629425299    22.9612813070203    23.0782665610982    23.1949988556084    23.3114584024278    23.4276254827613    23.5434804554365    23.6590037652004    23.7741759510141    23.8889776543494    24.0033896274833    24.1173927417946    24.2309679960590    24.3440965247448    24.4567596063089    24.5689386714917    24.6806153116135    24.7917712868696    24.9023885346262    25.0124491777157    25.1219355327329    25.2308301183300    25.3391156635127    25.4467751159356    25.5537916501978    25.6601486761387    25.7658298471334    25.8708190683886    25.9751005052380    26.0786585914379    26.1814780374631    26.2835438388023    26.3848412842538    26.4853559642211    26.5850737790085    26.6839809471169    26.7820640135392    26.8793098580560    26.9757057035313    27.0712391242082    27.1658980540041    27.2596707948069    27.3525460247703    27.4445128066094    27.5355605958967    27.6256792493570    27.7148590331637    27.8030906312344    27.8903651535260    27.9766741443309    28.0620095905721    28.1463639300994    28.2297300599846    28.3121013448172    28.3934716250003    28.4738352250458    28.5531869618704    28.6315221530909    28.7088366253202    28.7851267224627    28.8603893140098    28.9346218033358    29.0078221359933    29.0799888080092    29.1511208741798    29.2212179563668    29.2902802517928    29.3583085413370    29.4253041978307    29.4912691943530    29.5562061125265    29.6201181508128    29.6830091328082    29.7448835155393    29.8057463977587    29.8656035282405    29.9244613140760    29.9823268289694    30.0392078215333    30.0951127235842    30.1500506584387    30.2040314492083    30.2570656270958    30.3091644396903    30.3603398592634    30.4106045910644    30.4599720816159    30.5084565270100    30.5560728812031    30.6028368643122    30.6487649709102    30.6938744783217    30.7381834549183    30.7817107684148    30.8244760941642    30.8664999234537    30.9078035718003    30.9484091872463    30.9883397586550    31.0276191240064    31.0662719786928    31.1043238838141    31.1418012744739    31.1787314680751    31.2151426726150    31.2510639949816    31.2865254492487    31.3215579649719    31.3561933954840    31.3904645261906    31.4244050828661    31.4580497399487    31.4914341288367    31.5245948461837    31.5575694621942    31.5903965289195    31.6231155885532    31.6557671817267    31.6883928558052    31.7210351731827    31.7537377195783    31.7865451123314    31.8195030086975    31.8526581141437    31.8860581906445    31.9197520649774    31.9537896370183    31.9882218880374    32.0231008889946    32.0584798088355    32.0944129227864    32.1309556206506    32.1681644151037    32.2060969499891    32.2448120086139    32.2843695220444    32.3248305774017    32.3662574261575    32.4087134924294    32.4522633812768    32.4969728869964    32.5429090014181    32.5901399222001    32.6387350611250    32.6887650523952    32.7403017609286    32.7934182906543    32.8481889928080    32.9046894742278    32.9629966056499    33.0231885300040    33.0853446707091    33.1495457399690    33.2158737470682    33.2844120066671    33.3552451470980    33.4284591186606    33.5041412019175    33.5823800159901    33.6632655268539    33.7468890556344    33.8333432869025    33.9227222769705    34.0151214621873    34.1106376672341    34.2093691134204    34.3114154269792    34.4168776473628    34.5258582355384    34.6384610822839    34.7547915164830    34.8749563134217    34.9990637030830    35.1272233784432    35.2595465037671    35.3961457229040    35.5371351675831    35.6826304657089    35.8327487496574    35.9876086645714    36.1473303766559    36.3120355814743    36.4818475122433    36.6568909481293    36.8372922225435    37.0231792314376    37.2146814415997    37.4119298989495    37.6150572368345    37.8241976843249    38.0394870745098    38.2610628527928    38.4890640851872    38.7236314666120    38.9649073291876    39.2130356505310    39.4681620620517    39.7304338572476    40]
```

However the rectangle doesn't orient itself exactly towards the curve in question, it still has a offset.Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to indicate with the `quiver(x(k), y(k), 1, 1);`?

Comment: I wanted to indicate the direction of next point to move to, which i wrote wrong here in the question, this question is answered in a discord chatroom, i'll put the answer here, once again thank you very much for your time ViG :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i'm posting the solution to the question here. Thanks to anyone who took time to take a look at it.

```
      for k=2:length(x)
        %%%Plot road
        rl=-2; rr=0; w=4; l=100;
        yroad = 0:l;
        xroad = repmat(rl+w/2,l+1);
        plot(xroad, yroad, 'w--','LineWidth',1.5);
        hold on;
        rectangle('Position',[rl,rr,w,l],'FaceColor',[0 0 0 0.9]);
        axis([-4 4 0 50]);
        hold on;
        %%%%%
        set(gca,'children',flipud(get(gca,'children')))
        %%%time annotation
        str = strcat('t=',string(t));
        % annotation('textbox',[0.8 0.8 .5 .5],'String',str,'FitBoxToText','on');
        text(1,47,str,'Color','w')
        ratio = diff(get(gca, 'YLim'))/diff(get(gca, 'XLim'));
        phi = atan2(y(k) - y(k - 1), (x(k) - x(k - 1))*ratio);
        [x_rect_rot, y_rect_rot]=get_rectangle(phi, x(k), y(k));
        plot(polyshape(x_rect_rot, y_rect_rot),'FaceColor','c','FaceAlpha',0.85);
        hold on;
        plot(x(1:k), y(1:k));
        hold on;  
        drawnow;
      end

    function[xa,ya] =get_rectangle(phi,xc,yc,varargin)
        if length(varargin)<2
            h = 5;
            w = 3;
        else 
            h = varargin{4};
            w = varargin{5};
        end
        x_rect = [-h, h, h, -h]/2;
        y_rect = [-w, -w, w, w]/2;
        % Consider aspect ratio of the axis
        ratio = diff(get(gca, 'YLim'))/diff(get(gca, 'XLim'));            

        % Calculate rotated rectangle
        x_rect_rot = x_rect*cos(phi) - y_rect*sin(phi);
        y_rect_rot = x_rect*sin(phi) + y_rect*cos(phi);

        % Incorporate ratio
        x_rect_rot = x_rect_rot/ratio;

        % Calculate offset
        xa = x_rect_rot + xc;
        ya = y_rect_rot + yc;

    end
```